# Typescript strictNullChecks checking across functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

With `--strictNullChecks` enabled, tsc seems unable to infer that an optional property is not undefined if the check happens in a separate function. (See example, because I'm having trouble wording this clearly).

Given an interface with an optional property like

```
interface Foo {
    bar?: {
        baz: string;
    };
}
```

The following code compiles:

```
//compiles
function doStuff(foo: Foo) {
    if (foo.bar === undefined) {
        throw new Error("foo.bar must be defined");
    }
    foo.bar.baz;
}
```

And this code does not because tsc thinks foo.bar can be undefined:

```
//does not compile, foo.bar can be undefined
function doStuff2(foo: Foo) {
    validateFoo(foo);
    foo.bar.baz;
}

function validateFoo(foo: Foo) {
    if (foo.bar === undefined) {
        throw new Error("foo.bar must be defined");
    }
}
```

Why is this? Is there way to mark a function as a thing that can check for undefined and null? I'd like to avoid `foo.bar!.baz` if possible. In the example it's easy to inline the if/throw but if Foo has multiple optional properties that need to be checked in multiple functions it gets repetitive.

Comment: seems to be working for me here - https://jsfiddle.net/of5ja33v/

Comment: @gkb is there a way to specify in jsfiddle which version of tsc is used, and also use compiler flags? strictNullChecks is false by default and is only in typescript 2.0+

Comment: sorry, I completely missed there on strictNullChecks for tsc < 2.0+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this?

You could imagine TypeScript trying to inline the function for this, but to then get an accurate result you need to inline every function that `validateFoo` calls as well - this can go arbitrarily deep.

There's actually an entire discussion about this [here on TypeScript's issue tracker](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998).

> Is there way to mark a function as a thing that can check for undefined and null?

Sort of - there are type predicates, which are functions that tell TypeScript what a parameter's type if the function returns `true`.

```
function validateFoo(foo: Foo): foo is { bar: { baz: string } } {
    if (foo.bar === undefined) {
        throw new Error("foo.bar must be defined");
    }
    return true;
}
```

You could use it as follows:

```
function doStuff(foo: Foo) {
    if (!validateFoo(foo)) {
        throw foo;
    }
    foo.bar.baz;
}
```